# NIC bit/sec rate statistics

Tags: c, linux, networking

Which API  should I use to  get the current network bandwidth usage on linux.
I know that its can bee simply done with a script but can I get the same effect using C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `/proc/net/dev` twice, measuring the time between the reads, to estimate the bandwidth use. Longer intervals yield better results; I'd use at least a tenth of a second, perhaps a full second in between reads, for a reliable estimate.

The first two lines are header lines, followed by a line per device. See [`man 5 proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for details (most up to date reference being the [Linux man-pages project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/)). Both `netstat` and `ifconfig` utilities use this pseudo-file.

Here's what it looks like on my machine:

```
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
  eth0: 159107615  116900    0    0    0     0          0         0  7258457   88350    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo:  367802    2282    0    0    0     0          0         0   367802    2282    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

Note that this is a kernel pseudo-file, so never localized. The Linux kernel developers are quite strict about backwards compatibility, so while there might be new fields added to this pseudo-file, the existing fields will stay as they are.